# 'to do' or 'to make' a problem?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

Which word is more idiomatic with a problem, **to do** or **to make**?

> I don't like to **do/make** problems for people.

Answer (score 1):

To *do* problems isn't idiomatic, and when you use it, it carries a meaning of *solving* the (homework) problems. I don't think that's what you intended.

*Make* is better, but even more idiomatic are *cause* and *create*. This is supported by:

- Google Ngram's [list of verbs commonly found before 'problems'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_VERB+problems&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) (of course, you have to check the meaning; luckily problems, are more often *solved* than *caused*)
- the [Online OXFORD Collocation Dictionary](http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=problem):

  > **bring, cause, create** Success brings its own problems. Staff shortages cause problems for the organization.